# Apache Disk Cache Image 0kb

Tags: apache-2.4

I just set up the Apache cache by going through some tutorials and i followed the settings that was suggested in [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-content-caching-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Below are the configuration that i set in each `<VirtualHost>` container

```
CacheQuickHandler off

CacheLock on
CacheLockPath /tmp/mod_cache-lock
CacheLockMaxAge 5

CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie

<Location />
CacheEnable disk
CacheHeader on

CacheDefaultExpire 600
CacheMaxExpire 86400
CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.5

ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 minutes"

Header merge Cache-Control public
FileETag All
</Location>
```

After one day, some images are not appearing in the website and it shows `cached 0B` with `304 Not Modified`

with response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 07:06:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
ETag: "820f45-3823e-549b6f3b2a540"
Expires: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 07:11:28 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=300, public
```

Is there something wrong with the configuration?